# Can I access HSQL database from windows 8.1 store app?

Tags: windows-store-apps, hsqldb

I wanted to know if its possible to access HSQL db from windows store app. If not, which database can be accessed. Is there any other way of accessing stored data from my windows app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not access HSQL db directly from a windows store app.   You can use SQLite or Lex.DB directly from a windows store app as a local database. Typically you will need to create a web service to access a server side database from a windows store database. The only exception I know of is you can access a MySQL database on a server directly from a windows store app with the latest .net connector.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-rt.html